# unpivot the table for single column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to unpivot the table in sql but it's throwing an error. Help is appreciated

```
create table #test (id int ,GroupType varchar(50),State_NM varchar(20))

Insert Into #test values (100,  'Facility'  ,'TX')
Insert Into #test values (100,  'Group'     ,NULL)
Insert Into #test values (100,  'JobTitle'  ,'TX')
Insert Into #test values (100,  'JobTitle'  ,'NC')
Insert Into #test values (101,  'Facility'  ,'NM')
Insert Into #test values (101,  'Group'     ,'TX')
Insert Into #test values (102,  'Facility'  ,'TX')
Insert Into #test values (102,  'Group'     ,Null)
Insert Into #test values (102,  'Jobtitle'  ,'CA')

select * from #test

SELECT ID, facility,Group,JobTitle FROM   
(SELECT ID,GroupType,State_NM FROM #test )Tab1  
PIVOT  
(  
State_NM FOR GroupType IN ([facility],[Group[,[JobTitle])) AS Tab2  
ORDER BY Tab2.Name
```

Expected Result

[image]

Comment: Typo: `IN ([facility],[Group],[JobTitle]))`

Comment: @Charlieface even with the typo, jobtitle needs a string_agg()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `string_agg()` to "feed" your pivot

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d930c6da1cbaf4308b2c01ab4e7cc522)**

```
Select *
 From (
        select id
              ,GroupType
              ,Value = string_agg(state_NM,',')
         from #test
         Group by id,groupType
     ) src
 Pivot ( max(value) for GroupType IN ([facility],[Group],[JobTitle])) pvt
```

**Results**

```
id  facility    Group   JobTitle
100 TX          NULL    TX,NC
101 NM          TX      NULL
102 TX          NULL    CA
```

**UPDATE: <=2016 Version**

```
Select *
 From (
        select id
              ,GroupType
              ,Value = stuff( (Select ',' +state_NM From #test Where ID=A.ID and GroupType=A.GroupType For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
         From #test A
         Group By id,GroupType
     ) src
 Pivot ( max(value) for GroupType IN ([facility],[Group],[JobTitle])) pvt
```